# Nuget Package downloading Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus failed

Tags: c#, azure, nuget, azureservicebus

When I am trying to install **Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus** from Nuget Package Manager getting errors as mentioned in the images below
[image: Installing Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus with version 4.1.2]

See the below trace while installing the package from NuGet Package Manager
[image: LogTrace]

After the installing log trace, I am seeing this error

`Error The feed 'nuget.org [https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json]' lists package 'Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.1.0.3' but multiple attempts to download the nupkg have failed. The feed is either invalid or required packages were removed while the current operation was in progress. Verify the package exists on the feed and try again.
Unable to find package 'Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.1.0.3'.`

Could anyone please help me as I am not able to figure out what is going wrong.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

This issue may due to firewall or proxy settings, you can try to ping the specified url.

But as a workaround, you can download the [Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/) nugetpackage(`microsoft.azure.servicebus.4.1.2.nupkg`) to local, then install this package from local.

1.Nav to the [Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/) page, click "Download package":

[image]

2.After the package `microsoft.azure.servicebus.4.1.2.nupkg` is downloaded, go to visual studio -> Tools -> options-> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Sources, click "+" button, then specify Name and Source(the location where the microsoft.azure.servicebus.4.1.2.nupkg is located.):

[image]

3.Then right click the project -> Manage Nuget Packages, set the `Package source` as the one in step 2. Then you can see `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus` is there, just click install to install it:

[image]

Hope it can help.

Comment: @akhil, in which step? during download the .nupkg file or install it after download?

Comment: After setting the package source, when I clicked install. At the middle of  downloading I am getting a few errors like





  
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.runtime.interopservices/4.3.0/system.runtime.interopservices.4.3.0.nupkg
  Forbidden https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.runtime.extensions/4.3.0/system.runtime.extensions.4.3.0.nupkg 7008ms

  Forbidden https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.threading/4.3.0/system.threading.4.3.0.nupkg 4638ms

Comment: @akhil, can you attach a screenshot of how do you select package source, as I mentioned in step 3?

Comment: Please check the links
Step 3: https://imgur.com/N4NF0hS
Step 2: https://imgur.com/xnGbEwO
and please say where did I go wrong

Comment: @akhil, you can download each of .nupkg files which has an forbidden error, then put them into the source location in your local computer. For example, for `system.runtime.interopservices.4.3.0.nupkg`, go to [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime.InteropServices/), and download the .nupkg file(select the correct version, for this one, please download version 4.3.0).

Comment: There are so many forbidden errors nearly more than 30 forbidden files, Is there any alternative way to download all files relative that package???. By the way thanks for taking the pain for helping me to solve the error.

Comment: @akhil, you may check if you have set any proxy / firewall to block these requests?